# How to make Delete button to remove LI element in the code below?

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning Javascript to understand it better. When you add an item to the list, I would like to have a delete button to remove it.

It seems to me when I do `deleteButton.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild()`, it should remove the `li` element, but not sure why this is not working.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucheron/XVq3n/18/

```
addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
clearButton = document.getElementById('clearButton');
deleteButton = document.getElementById('deleteButton');

addButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById('listItem').value;
    var addItem = document.getElementById('output');
    var entry = document.createElement("li");
    text += ' <button id="deleteButton">Delete</button>';
    entry.innerHTML = text;    
    addItem.appendChild(entry);
});

clearButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var text = document.getElementById('listItem');
    var addItem = document.getElementById('output');
    addItem.innerHTML = '';
    text.value = '';
});

deleteButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    deleteButton.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild();
});
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery actually? The question tag makes it seem like you might. If so there is shorter/simpler to follow methods of doing what you are doing.

Comment: If you are looking for an solution without jQuery(which I assume you are looking for) remove the jQuery tag

Comment: oh sorry, I am not. just trying to be familiar with the fundamentals without using jQuery. I am practicing for interviews so just want to be more fluent in case I get asked.

Answer (score 3):

If you see your browser console there is an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null` it is because there is no element with id `deleteButton` when the page is loaded.

Also note that the ID of an element must be unique in a document, so since you are adding multiple delete buttons use a class attribute to group them.

Your code should be

```
//wait for the window onload event
window.onload = function () {
    var addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
    var clearButton = document.getElementById('clearButton');

    addButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var text = document.getElementById('listItem').value;
        var addItem = document.getElementById('output');
        var entry = document.createElement("li");
        entry.innerHTML = text;

        //create a button element
        var btn = document.createElement("Button");
        btn.innerHTML = 'Delete';
        //add button to li
        entry.appendChild(btn);
        //add a click handler to the button
        btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            //delete the parent li
            this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
        });

        addItem.appendChild(entry);
    });

    clearButton.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        var text = document.getElementById('listItem');
        var addItem = document.getElementById('output');
        addItem.innerHTML = '';
        text.value = '';
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JM7mu/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you tag `jQuery`, you can use a technique call [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on('click','.deleteButton', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();    
});
```

In this case, It will helps you to bind the click event to the dynamically created delete button.

Btw, because `id` is unique so you should use class instead of id for your button

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XVq3n/20/)**

Comment: But that selector uses the class `deleteButton`, not the id (which he is wrongly duplicating)